# How to create a HttpServer in JAVA support long connection?

Tags: java, http

I notice that http1.1 support long connection.
If Keep-Alive is true, the tcp connection won't close after the request was done.
But if I try to create a server use ServerSocket.
Everytime I handle the request, I will send the response to the client, then I have to close to socket (Close tcp connection)
So how to reuse the tcp connection?

The reason why i have to close socket is that the browser have to aware that the connection is finished.

The code like this

```
ServerSocket serverSocket; 
        while (true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            thread{
                request = socket.readRequest();
                socket.writeHttpResponse();
                socket.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why would you **have to** close the socket?

Comment: You cannot reuse the tcp `connection`, when you close the connection. But you can create a new connection reusing the `Socket` by calling `socket = serverSocket.accept();`. This will (re)create a new connection.

Comment: Unless you're an absolute expert in socket programming and want to create a new web server, you should really stop using sockets to deal with HTTP. Use a proper HTTP library/server (netty, jetty, tomcat, etc.). If you really want to do that with socket programming, then you really need to learn the HTTP protocol. It allows reusing the connection for several requests and responses. That means the connection does not have to be closed.

Comment: I just want to learn HTTP proto by writing this code. And Have No Idea how to keep the long connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, we don't have to  close the socket.
When we send the HTTP response , the browser will know the end of the response according to Content-Length in Request Header.
When we finish sendind the Response to the browser, if we holding the socket inpustream, we can continue get the enxt request from that socket Only if we use 1.1 proto and have a header of Connection:Keep-Alive.